# How do I shift panel applets to the far left?

Tags: raspbian, pixel

I have raspbian, with the pixel desktop.
I can add panel applets by going to panel preferences, but they always go to the far right. I want the panel applets next to the Raspberry, on the far left. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Panel Preferences, you can select your panel in "Currently loaded plugins", and move it "up" or "down", which means left or right if you have a horisontal panel.